# Login form error messages

Tags: form

I am looking for some advice on how best to add error messages (eg incorrect password / username) on a custom Login form.

Tried the usual routes for documentation but have seen nothing as yet - all help appreciated.

Dan

Comment: I'm having the same issue, following the docs with: `{% if errorMessage is defined %} {{ errorMessage }} {% endif %}` But receiving no error messages if email or password are invalid: http://melnet.org.nz/professionals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any login validation errors are passed back to the form and available via the Twig `{{ errorMessage }}` variable.

You can see an example of how to display them on a login form here: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/login-form

Comment: Thanks Brad - totally missed that and useful to know. Error messages may be a good section for the docs, as it's something always found in the other topic areas.